# Laravel Vite @apply tailwind custom styles are not compiled

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

I'm using Laravel Vite and have this in my app.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import 'animate/base.css';
@import 'animate/animations.css';

@layer components {
  .ql-container {
        @apply border-2 border-slate-300;
    }
}
```

And postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

The `ql-container` custom Tailwind styles are not getting compiled and I'm not sure why. This is how it's defined in the Tailwind docs.

Comment: `border-3` isn't a valid utility: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width

Comment: @ChenBr good catch, although this does not seem to be the issue. I have updated the question, with `border-2` it also doesn't work.

Comment: Is the class `ql-container` actually being used in your templates somewhere? Otherwise it won't be included in the css output.

Comment: Hmm that’s probably it @stickyuser. This is for QuillJS which dynamically creates an element with this class through some javascript. Do you know if you can tell Tailwind in the config to not ignore this class while compiling if it doesn’t exist? If so I can test that and accept it as an answer if it works.

Comment: Just don't wrap the style with `@layer components { ... }`. If it is not wrapped in that then it will always be added to the css output. Does that make sense?

Comment: @stickyuser yep that works! Please feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class `ql-container` is added inside an `@layer` directive and its use is not detected by Tailwind in any of your templates, then it will not be included in the css output.

If it is not wrapped in a directive then it will always be added to the css output, so just don't wrap the style with `@layer components { ... }`.